# Validation of availability for a new order

Tags: postgresql, query, trigger, join

I have a management application of sales, stock and payment on a warehouse whole saler from a web interface. In particular, when a order is effectuated it must create a line corresponding to each product ordered with the respective quantity. The validation of the stock availability is done at the moment of the order.

Considering the following two ways of validation on order:

1. Use a trigger `BEFORE INSERT` on the table `OrderLine`, that does a SELECT on `Product` verifying there is enough stock.
2. Do a `SELECT ... FROM OrderLine JOIN Product WHERE quant < stock`.

My question is: Which of these two alternatives is preferable, and why / for what scenario?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter It's PostgreSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only see you doing a `SELECT` in both variants. If you want to make sure you don't sell more than you have in store (stock), you must decrease your stock in the same transaction you place the order. Use a [data-modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) for the job (Postgres 9.1 or later):

```
WITH u AS (
   UPDATE product SET quant = quant - <put_order_quant_here>
   WHERE  product_id = <order_prod_id>
   AND    quant >= <put_order_quant_here>
   RETURNING product_id, <put_order_quant_here> AS quant
   )
INSERT INTO order_detail (order_id, product_id, quant)
SELECT <put_order_id_here>, product_id, quant
FROM   u;
```

The `UPDATE` in the CTE only returns values if the product has sufficient stock (and it takes a write lock on the row). In this case, the quantity is reduced in the same transaction, just before the order is placed.

Put all order-details into one transaction, if any of them fails to `INSERT` then `ROLLBACK`.

#### Possible deadlocks

This scenario can easily lead to deadlocks. Say, you have two orders coming in at the same time, both want product A and B. The first order starts with A, the second starts with B. Then the two transactions block each other out. Each waits for the other to complete. A [deadlock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-DEADLOCKS) ensues.

In PostgreSQL a transaction will wait for some time when it is stalled by locks. Depending on your setting of [`deadlock_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-locks.html#GUC-DEADLOCK-TIMEOUT) (default is 1 sesond), checks for possible deadlocks are performed.

Once detected, one transaction is aborted and a deadlock exception reported. The other one can finish. Which one is hard to predict.

There is a simple way to avoid this kind of deadlocks: Always place your `order_details` in a **consistent order**. Like products ordered by `product_id`. This way, the above scenario can never happen.

Comment: Nice, and certainly a PostgreSQL solution as Oracle (as of 11.2) can't do an `UPDATE` in a CTE. +1

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.1's docs say that using transactions at the serializable isolation level can't cause a deadlock. (Search http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html for "causing a deadlock".) At least I think that's what it says.

Comment: @Catcall: but that isolation level can report serialization failures instead (and more often than actual deadlocks would occur). So the app would have to retry transaction on serialization failure. For the scenario at hand it should be sufficient, simpler and faster to just place order_details in a consistent order.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

I made this post before the postgresql tag was added, but the concepts should be similar.  Basically you need to be able to lock the record in some way to ensure that the stock value you select remains the stock value you decrease.  The same transaction that locks the record should update the stock and insert into the OrderLine table.  As soon as you determine that stock isn't available roll the whole transaction back.

If this processing is done in a batch operation by one process then you don't need to be concerned with locking individual records, but you should ensure that only one batch process can be running at the same time.

---

Look into...

1. The [WAIT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2065706) clause of the SELECT statement.
2. The [BULK COLLECT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#BABEIACI) clause of the SELECT statement.
3. The [FORALL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/forall_statement.htm#LNPLS01321) statement.

You probably also would want to ensure that all entries had enough stock, so you may want some to aggregate whether the stock is available or not.

Comment: I know fegol's not using SQL Server because of the natural join, but do we know it's Oracle?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sorry, It's PostgreSQL

Comment: @Aaron, fegol - Sorry about that, made an assumption.

Comment: @LeighRiffel: I would expect that multiple processes can run at a time. PostgreSQL transactions acquire locks along the way and release them on commit / rollback. As long as order details are placed in a **consistent order**, concurrency should be no problem, at least with my query. Later concurrent transactions competing for the same product wait for the earlier to finish and then proceed accordingly. The MVCC model with its default [read committed isolation level](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED) should handle that gracefully.

Comment: @Erwin My "lock the record in some way" does not exclude implicit locks that solutions such as yours employ. Consistent order only prevents deadlocks in a properly locking application.  If multiple processes are selecting stock and then updating it without having the record locked then there will be problems regardless of the consistency of the order.

Comment: @LeighRiffel: Rows that are updated are locked automatically in Postgres - and cannot be updated by another transaction until the lock is released (commit / rollback). My suggested path always tries to update needed products for an order first. This will have to wait for concurrent earlier transactions ordering from the same product to finish. Everything should work just fine. Or course, a `CHECK` constraint must be in place to disallow negative `product.quant`.

Comment: @Erwin "locked automatically" = "implicit locks" i.e. we have been in agreement.  My comment was intended to clarify the pitfall of using multiple processes that do not lock, not to contend with your solution which does lock (implicitly).

Comment: @LeighRiffel: Right, we have an accord. It would seem I was more verbose than necessary.