# Update "oldest" row

Tags: postgresql, update, performance, subquery, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-performance

I need to update the "oldest" row in the database (for now, its limit 1, but I need to also be able to set it to `n`).

I'm essentially doing a constant stream of "update the oldest rows and retrieve them at the same time".

The column is indexed, it's called `last_sent_at` and I'm calling it ~20K times a minute.

The thing is, `last_sent_at` can be `NULL` and that should always be favored over ones with a filled in time. Once all of them are filled in it should choose the "oldest".

This works for me, the problem is I don't know if its efficient, and it also doesn't work when I need to update 5 rows at once. I guess I could use `IN` I'm just afraid it would be inefficient.

```
UPDATE subscribers
SET last_sent_at = '2018-11-17 00:02:27'
WHERE id = (
  SELECT id
  FROM subscribers
  ORDER BY last_sent_at NULLS FIRST
  LIMIT 1
)
RETURNING id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table is big, the key to performance is a matching index on `(last_sent_at NULLS FIRST)`.

Since you are updating so much, have aggressive `VACUUM` settings. This can be adjusted per table. See:

- [Aggressive Autovacuum on PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/aggressive-autovacuum-on-postgresql)

For only a *single* row, `UPDATE` with a subquery like you have is fine.

For `LIMIT N` with *N > 1* a CTE is your safe bet. Like:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT id
   FROM   subscribers
   ORDER  BY last_sent_at NULLS FIRST
   LIMIT  5
   )
UPDATE subscribers s
SET    last_sent_at = '2018-11-17 00:02:27'
FROM   cte
WHERE  s.id = cte.id
RETURNING id;
```

If you do this under concurrent write load, add another expression to your `ORDER BY` to make the order deterministic. And add the same expression to your index to match! (There can be many rows with `NULL`, right?) And use the same order for all commands taking row locks in the same table. Else you might face **deadlocks** from multiple transaction taking locks in arbitrary order. Better yet, use `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` if you are not absolutely bound to the strict order. Closely related, with in-depth explanation:

- [Postgres UPDATE ... LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1/69497#69497)

Related:

- [Deadlock best practices](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125289/deadlock-best-practices/125339#125339)
- [Optimizing concurrent updates in Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/optimizing-concurrent-updates-in-postgres/68398#68398)

Comment: There will definitely be very heavy write load but it will be all INSERT statements of new records, not modifying any existing records. Sorry I'm not A super DB expert, but are deadlocks possible which "stop" the entire database? or is it a temporary very quick issue. Thank you so much, I will read those

Comment: I guess this is really stupid but I didn't think a deadlock was possible if I'm just writing "normal" queries. I thought postgres handled all of that in a sort of synchronous way

Comment: Deadlocks in your case are resolved automatically by killing one or more of the contesting transactions. Details: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12984/3684 And, well, *"a sort of synchronous way"* is achieved by taking locks in a consistent order - the point above exactly.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will need to really read into this. i wasn't even aware this was a thing. By this: "if you are not absolutely bound to the strict order" does this mean it still selects the 5 oldest records, but they will be in a different order WITHIN the 5 results (that's ok because they're all getting the same time anyway).

Comment: @Tallboy: By that I honor the possibility that `SKIP LOCKED` can skip over the "oldest" rows because it's currently locked - for whatever reason, even a concurrent transaction trying to do the same update (which might still fail, we don't know until it's committed).

Comment: Ok I see... I think that's ok because it will just be caught in the next pass. Now I need to go read about all of this. Do you know of a 'beginner' place to read what causes a deadlock? I will still read all those links you sent

Comment: This should be instrumental understand deadlocks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22776994/939860

Comment: thanks so much. Down the rabbit hole i descend